# Progress OpenEdge 12.2.7 Windows server 2019 Standard Microsoft Office 365 received message 3153 DDE initiate failed

Tags: excel, openedge, progress-4gl

We have an ABL program that sends the data shown in a screen browse to excel.  It executes fine when Office is installed in the server.  When using Office 365 in gives message 3153 DDE initiate failed.
Below is the code used.  Notice that we load a variable with the excel path.  Is this the correct path for OFFICE 365?  Any ideas why the DDE is failing?

```
DEFINE VARIABLE EE-EXCELON     AS LOGICAL INITIAL FALSE.

DEFINE VARIABLE EE-DIRECTORY   AS CHAR FORMAT "X(100)" NO-UNDO.

DEFINE VARIABLE EE-INPUT-FILE  AS CHAR NO-UNDO.

DEFINE FRAME EE-MAINFRAME WITH SIDE-LABELS. 

DEFINE VARIABLE RESULT         AS INTEGER.

ENABLE ALL WITH FRAME EE-MAINFRAME TITLE "Worksheet Monitor".
 
PROCEDURE WinExec EXTERNAL "kernel32.dll":   /*-Run Windows application----*/
    
    DEFINE INPUT PARAMETER EE-PROGRAM    AS CHARACTER.

    DEFINE INPUT PARAMETER EE-PROG-STYLE AS LONG.

    DEFINE RETURN PARAMETER RESULT AS LONG.

END PROCEDURE.  
 
   
**EE-DIRECTORY = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\".**

EE-INPUT-FILE = EE-DIRECTORY + "Excel /e".


RUN WinExec (INPUT EE-INPUT-FILE,INPUT 1, OUTPUT RESULT). /* INPUT: 1=normal 2=minimized */

IF RESULT > 32
THEN
DO:
    ASSIGN  EE-EXCELON = TRUE.

    
    IF j > 2 THEN
    DO:

        WKFILE.CHAR1 = EE-DIRECTORY.
        RELEASE wkfile.
    END.

END.

ELSE
DO:

    IF j > 4 THEN
    DO:
        MESSAGE "Excel Directory - not found" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
        RETURN.
    END.

END.

 
 CREATE "Excel.Application" hExcel.

 IF NOT VALID-HANDLE(hExcel) THEN RETURN.

    hExcel:Visible = FALSE. 

 DDE INITIATE EE-SYS FRAME FRAME EE-MAINFRAME:HANDLE
    APPLICATION "Excel" TOPIC "System".


 IF EE-SYS = 0 THEN
 DO:
   MESSAGE "Excel not available" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
   RETURN.
 END.

 DDE EXECUTE EE-SYS COMMAND "[new(1)]".

 DDE INITIATE EE-SHEET FRAME FRAME EE-MAINFRAME:HANDLE
   APPLICATION "Excel" TOPIC "Sheet1".
END.
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm failing to understand what  you are really trying to do. If you want to open up excel and create a new sheet you can stick with COM Automation. You don't need the DDE-parts. Also you don't need to run excel (RUN WinExec).

Opening Excel and creating a workbook with a sheet:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE chExcel AS COM-HANDLE NO-UNDO. 
DEFINE VARIABLE chWorkbook AS COM-HANDLE NO-UNDO. 
create "Excel.Application" chExcel no-error. 
chExcel:visible = YES. 
/* Add a new workbook */ 
chWorkbook = chExcel:Workbooks:Add(). 
/* Select a worksheet */ 
chWorkbook:Worksheets(1):Activate.
```

This is taken from https://community.progress.com/s/article/Can-not-start-Microsoft-Excel-using-com-automation

Comment: We have a screen program that uses an open query to display a browse.  We use this logic to send the data in each cell to an excel sheet